# django Image field is not loading current value on edit form and user have to upload again the file

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I have a django form that have 3 image fields that are required. What I found is that when I use an instance to create an update form, the image is not loaded un the html input field, so when I send the form to the view to save it into database, I get an invalid form error due to images are missing.

I defined the imageField as FileField:

```
class Meta:
        model = Edicion
        exclude = ['festival']
        widgets = {
            'logo': FileInput,
            'banner': FileInput,
            'poster': FileInput,
            'fecha_apertura_inscripciones': DateInput(),
            'fecha_cierre_inscripciones': DateInput(),
            'fecha_inicio': DateInput(),
            'fecha_final': DateInput(),
            'fecha_notificacion': DateInput(),
        }
```

[image: Text]

If I define again these fields then it works fine, but i'm not being able to send this field from the view.

Many thanks

Edit:
Form Code:

Form.py

```
class createNewEdicion(forms.ModelForm):
    required_css_class = 'required-field'

    class Meta:
        model = Edicion
        exclude = ['festival']
        widgets = {
            'logo': FileInput,
            'banner': FileInput,
            'poster': FileInput,
            'fecha_apertura_inscripciones': DateInput(),
            'fecha_cierre_inscripciones': DateInput(),
            'fecha_inicio': DateInput(),
            'fecha_final': DateInput(),
            'fecha_notificacion': DateInput(),
        }
        
        help_texts = {
            'Nombre': ('Some useful help text.'),
        }
        error_messages = {
            'Nombre': {
                'max_length': ("This writer's name is too long."),
            },
        }
```

View.py

```
if request.method == 'POST':
        form_festival = createNewFestival(request.POST, request.FILES)
        form_edicion = createNewEdicion(request.POST, request.FILES)
        # check whether it's valid:
        if form_festival.is_valid() and form_edicion.is_valid():
            festival.nombre_contacto = form_festival.cleaned_data['nombre_contacto']
            festival.save()

            festival.edicion.banner = form_edicion.cleaned_data['banner']
            festival.edicion.logo = form_edicion.cleaned_data['logo']
            festival.edicion.poster = form_edicion.cleaned_data['poster']
            festival.edicion.save()
```

How I create the forms:

```
form_festival = createNewFestival(instance=festival)
    form_edicion = createNewEdicion(instance=edicio)
```

template

```
<div class="tab">
        <h2>Información de la edición</h2>
        <div class="grid-form-2">
            <div class="fieldWrapper">
                {{ form_edicion.nombre.errors }}
                {{ form_edicion.nombre.label_tag }}
                {{ form_edicion.nombre }}
            </div>

            <div class="fieldWrapper">
                {{ form_edicion.banner.errors }}
                {{ form_edicion.banner.label_tag }}
                {{ form_edicion.banner }}
            </div>

            <div class="fieldWrapper">
                {{ form_edicion.poster.errors }}
                {{ form_edicion.poster.label_tag }}
                {{ form_edicion.poster }}
            </div>

            <div class="fieldWrapper">
                {{ form_edicion.logo.errors }}
                {{ form_edicion.logo.label_tag }}
                {{ form_edicion.logo }}
            </div>
```

This is not all the code as its a long class.

Comment: can you put your form code

Comment: Share the HTML for code as well as the view.

Comment: Done, (the part that afect this)

Comment: @marccgcom please share the view by which you are rendering the form one possible error might be your form type which must be set to multipart

Comment: I have this. The form works fine as a new one; <form id="regForm" method="post" action="{{post_url}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">

Comment: @marccgcom: since you use `form_edicion = createNewEdicion(instance=edicio)`, it suggests you want to *edit* the instance, not create one?

Comment: Can you also share the model? It might help to provide an MWE such that it can be reproduced locally.

Comment: Yes the problem is editing the form because the fieldInput in htyml appears empty. Creation works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass the instance to the form when editing too, so:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form_festival = createNewFestival(
        request.POST, request.FILES, instance=festival
    )
    form_edicion = createNewEdicion(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=edicio)
    # check whether it's valid:
    if form_festival.is_valid() and form_edicion.is_valid():
        form_festival.save()
        form_edicion.save()
        return redirect('name-of-some-view')
else:
    form_festival = createNewFestival(instance=festival)
    form_edicion = createNewEdicion(instance=edicio)
```

---

> **Note**: Usually a `Form` or a `ModelForm` ends with a `…Form` suffix,
> to avoid collisions with the name of the model, and to make it clear that we are
> working with a *form*. Therefore it might be better to use `FestivalForm` instead of
> <s>`createNewFestival`</s>.

Comment: Thats really great. It worked and I understand why. I will also check yor naiming advice as all good practices are really good to implement. Many thanks